# Extracting data from one excel workbook into another using VBA Macro - Error #9

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy a certain range of cells from a password - protected Excel workbook (oldata) and paste it onto another workbook (newdata - no password). However, I keep encountering 'Error 9: Subscript out of range' every time I try running my code. Not entirely sure where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much! :)

```
sub extractdata()
dim oldata as Workbook
dim newdata as Workbook 

set oldata = Workbooks.Open("path to the file")
set newdata = Workbooks.Open("path to the file")

oldata.Worksheets("Sheet name").Range("A8:B8").Copy_     ###Error 9
newdata.Worksheets("Sheetname").Range("D8:E8")           ###Error 9

oldata.Close
end sub
```

I am pretty sure that I am using the correct names for the workbooks and worksheets. Not sure why or how to work around Error 9. Is there any other way of copying and pasting cells' values from one workbook to another? Thank you for all of your help! :)

Comment: Looks like your sheet names are not correct.  It's better to ocpy/paste your code directly from the VB editor rather than re-type it (as it seems you did here), to reduce the chance of typos in your posted code.

Comment: Thank you for our response, Tim! I will keep that in mind. But, for this code, I am 100% sure that my sheet names are correct. Don't know where else could I be going wrong. Once again, I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: The name of the sheet I am copying from does have a space in between the two words....I don't know if that has any influence on the code...

Comment: If it's throwing error 9, the sheet names don't exist. Watch for leading or trailing spaces, and yes, every character must match *exactly*. `Sheetname` isn't `Sheet name` and isn't `Sheetname_` or `_SheetName` either.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mathieu! That makes sense.... but, I have tried every possible scenario with the names...and it still gives me the same error. And I can't edit the workbook as its password protected. Is there some other method of copying and pasting a range of cells from one workbook to another? I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much! :)